# Location-Based Service Application

Tags: android, dictionary, user-location

I need to be able to locate the user in a building, show the route that can be taken, and optionally download the building's map, and use the turn-by turn navigation without any internet/GPS access after that.

My main questions are;
1) How do I get a building's map? For example I wanted to have a map of my university campus, where do I get the map from? Google Map?
2) How to implement the turn-by-turn navigation without any internet/GPS? Only the graphical is enough, no need for sound support.
3) How do i obtain user's location using Wi-Fi connection instead of GPS?

I am not hoping for source codes, I just need guidance and directions on where should I look, and what I need to study.

Comment: I would ask your campus for a map.  And because of GPS precision, which is rarely down to smaller than 100ft, GPS will be of little use inside a building.

Comment: A WiFi connection cannot be used to locate someone except to say "this person is in range of that WiFi access point".  It will provide no information as to whether the person is inside the building or outside the building, let alone what room the user is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a tough assignment. I imagine you have to create the building map yourself. Perhaps to start off, you can write an application which records the signal strengths of all wifi signals in a given building while you walk around in it. So, say there are 7 wifi access points you will have a database of signal strength vectors `{w_i_1,w_i_2,...,w_i_7}`.

With this database you can then compare to a new unknown signal `{v1, v2, ..., v7}` so you have some idea of where you are (find the minimal norm of `w-v` for each `w_i`).

Finally store 'special' locations (where you reach a left/right/straight decision point and
have your app guide the user which way to go to get to their destination.

Comment: Okay, I see the pattern now. My lecturer actually made it specific that I am going to use 3 Wi-Fi Access Points to get the user location.

Comment: Any sample project or codes for me to refer? I am not sure what keywords to search for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How do I get a building's map? For example I wanted to have a map of my university campus, where do I get the map from? Google Map?

Unless your campus is huge enough, Google static maps won't be practical enough. There is no place where you can download the blueprint of a building. That only happens in Hollywood movies.

- You draw it yourself.
- Download it from [The internet](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=map%20of%20stanford%20university&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=986&bih=641&sei=qJHUTpqcCI_zmAXXwPly).
- Talk to some lecturer from your campus, he might know where the map for you campus lies.

> 2) How to implement the turn-by-turn navigation without any internet/GPS?

Without Internet or GPS, you only have Wifi and Gyro sensors to help you. Here [is a paper that compares Route Navigation algorithms](http://alexandria.tue.nl/extra2/200412420.pdf). You'll have to study [map matching algorithms](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=map%20matching%20algorithm%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a). Here is [a java project](http://codesearch.google.com/#8SMNiUpcFlI/trunk/mapsforge/src/org/mapsforge/directions/TurnByTurnDescription.java&type=cs) that you may use as a reference.

> 3) How do i obtain user's location using Wi-Fi connection instead of GPS?

You will need an access to a [WiFi database](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/developers/sdk.php) to triangulate your position. Once you get a lat, lon fix. You do what Arnoud suggested and create your own WiFi positioning system.

Comment: AArgh now I need to play with Wi-Fi database... I am not too familiar with networking programming...